# VS Code Suggestion doesn't work correctly

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code, I typing `btn-` and press `CTRL+SPACE`. After suggest I select `btn-primary` and press `Enter`. It should be complete `btn-` but it append like this `btn-btn-primary`.

VS Code make it only when string ends with `-`. How can I solve it?

I have one more question, VS Code doesn't show suggestions when I key press. Eg. `class="btn` not trigger suggestions. But `class="{something} btn` it will triggered suggestion correctly! I want to trigger suggestion if I press two or more letters and when it matches any suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the version `1.67.x` VS Code suggestion problem resolved when we use the hyphen. It correct complete `btn-` and `~{primary}` correctly. But still class' first words does not trigger the suggestion dropdown.

```
Version: 1.67.2 (user setup)
Date: 2022-05-17T18:15:52.058Z
Electron: 17.4.1
Chromium: 98.0.4758.141
Node.js: 16.13.0
V8: 9.8.177.13-electron.0
```